# How to correct the size of the swf movie clip in a scroll pane in adobe flash cs6 as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs5

I have placed a scroll pane from the components tab in adobe flash. I also placed the correct source in the parameter of the scroll pane. However, instead of showing the correct resolution size, its only displaying the corner of the movie clip. Thank you for the help!

1. I did not create a scroll pane thru as3. I just dragged and dropped the pre made scroll pane from the components tab.
2. I have searched for answers everywhere, but I can't make it work.
3. The scroll pane width and the swf width is the same. only the height differs
4. Most importantly, I'm an AS3 beginner. Sorry.

I badly need your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should get you started?

https://griffinsdesigns.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/custom-actionscript-3-scrollpane-component-with-oop/

Doing a bunch of beginner tutorials should help before you start doing more advanced stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:
`ScrollPane(yourScrollPane).setSize(300,225);`
`ScrollPane(yourScrollPane).source = scrollMc;`
`ScrollPaneyourScrollPane).source as MovieClip;`
Where scrollMC is the MovieClip that you want to be contained within the scrollpane.